# Is "A with B" a type?

Tags: scala, inheritance, mixins

In Scala we use mix-in like this:

```
class C extends A with B
```

I understand this declaration as `C` is a subclass of `A with B`. Is this true? Or `C` is just subclass of both `A` and `B`(I don't think it's possible on JVM which doesn't support multi-inheritance)?

If `A with B` is a type, why doesn't this line work?

```
classOf[A with B]
```

Another reason why I consider `A with B` a type is the fact that it can be used in pattern match:

```
val c = new C
val u = c match { case a: A with B => 1 } // 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala supports multiple inheritance via **traits**. Any class can extend 0 or 1 class, but can also "mix in" any number of traits. (There is a bit of compiler magic that rearranges things behind the scenes to conform to the JVM's limitations) The syntax is along the lines of

```
class MyClass extends [ClassOrTrait] with [Trait] with [AnotherTrait] with ...
```

So your class C definition is more like

`class ((C extends A) with B)` than like `class (C extends (A with B))`

`A with B` is a type, and can be used as a type alias, but the `classOf` method wants a class:

```
scala> type AB = A with B
defined type alias AB

scala> classOf[AB]
<console>:11: error: class type required but A with B found
              classOf[AB]
                      ^
```

vs

```
scala> class AB extends A with B
defined class AB

scala> classOf[AB]
res12: Class[AB] = class AB
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Dylan. `A with B` is only a type definition. However for it to work with `classOf[T]` , it needs to have a Java **class** or **interface** generated by Scala.

```
scala> trait A
defined trait A

scala>   trait B
defined trait B

scala>   trait AB extends A with B
defined trait AB

scala>   class C extends A with B
defined class C

scala>   type TypeAB = A with B
defined type alias TypeAB

scala>   println(classOf[A])
interface $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$A

scala>   println(classOf[B])
interface $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$B

scala>   println(classOf[AB] )
interface $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$AB

scala>   println(classOf[C])
class $line6.$read$$iw$$iw$C

scala>   println(TypeAB)
<console>:8: error: not found: value TypeAB
                println(TypeAB)
                        ^

scala> classOf[TypeAB]
<console>:11: error: class type required but A with B found
              classOf[TypeAB]
```

Also it is interesting that Scala *does* manage to match the `with` in case constructs.